# Celery: Getting unexpected run_command() takes 1 positional argument but 318 were given error

Tags: django, rabbitmq, task, celery

I am attempting to run an async task and am getting an unexpected error: run_command() takes 1 positional argument but 318 were given. 
I have a list of commands that I want to run from a celery task.

```py
run_command.chunks(iter(commands), 10).group().apply_async()

@task
def run_command(commands):
    for command in commands:
        print("RUNNING, ", command)
        print("Pid: ", os.getpid())
        os.system(command)
```

As shown above, I am attempting to break down my command into batches that will be executed in parallel.

Thanks for the help

Comment: It here passes the commands as positional parameters.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, any suggestions on how I could potentially prevent this, if it is the issue?

Comment: wrap the items in singleton tuples before passing it to `iter(..)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Celery treats its positional arguments as `*args`, so every *command* in your *commands* iterable should looks like `('commandtext',)`

```
commands = ['hello', 'world', '!']

@task
def run_command(command):
    '''run command'''

run_command.chunks(zip(commands), 2).group().apply_async()
```